# how to change chart type based on user slection radion button in bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmx7i.png)   I want to change bokeh chart at run time when click on a radio button. Here is what I've tried till now:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.core.properties import value
from bokeh.models.widgets import Paragraph,PreText,RadioButtonGroup
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.models.widgets import CheckboxGroup, RadioGroup
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource,LabelSet,CustomJS,Row
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show,save
from bokeh.transform import dodge
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis

colors = ["#c9d9d3", "#718dbf", "#e84d60"]

dataframe = pd.read_csv('Experience.csv')

source = ColumnDataSource(dataframe)
exp = dataframe['Experience']
ys = list(dataframe.keys())
ys.remove('Experience')
TOOLTIPS = [("Experience", "@Experience")]

p = figure(x_range=exp, y_range=(0, 100), plot_height=350, tools=['hover','save','reset','zoom_out','zoom_in','pan','box_zoom'],tooltips=TOOLTIPS)
stacked = p.vbar_stack(stackers=ys, x='Experience',color=colors,source=source,legend=[value(x) for x in ys],name=ys,width=0.5,)

colorList = Viridis[len(ys)]
labels = []
for y, offset, color in zip(ys, [-0.25, 0, 0.25], colorList):
    bar = p.vbar(x=dodge('Experience', offset, range=p.x_range), top=y, width=0.2, source=source, legend=y + ' ', color=color)
    bar.visible = False

radiogroup = RadioGroup(labels = ["StackedBar", "Bar"], active = 0,)
radiogroup.callback = CustomJS(args = dict(stacked = stacked, bar = bar), code = """
    for (i in stacked)
        stacked[i].visible = false;

    bar.visible = false;

    if (cb_obj.active == 0)
        for (i in stacked)
            stacked[i].visible = true;
    else if (cb_obj.active == 1)
        bar.visible = true; """)

layout = Row(p, radiogroup)
show(layout)
```

It is showing two graphs in one figure, but I want bar graph default and when I click on the radio button the graph should change based on click event.here is my full code..pl check and tell what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

The `vbar_stack` returns a list of glyphs so you need to toggle visibility each of them separately like this:

```
from bokeh.plotting import show, figure
from bokeh.models import RadioGroup, CustomJS, Row
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource
import pandas as pd

data = {'fruits' : ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries'],
        '2015'   : [2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4],
        '2016'   : [5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6],
        '2017'   : [3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['total'] = df.sum(axis = 1)

p = figure(x_range = data['fruits'], title = "Fruit Counts by Year", tools = "hover", tooltips = "$name     @fruits: @$name")

vbar_stack = p.vbar_stack(["2015", "2016", "2017"], x = 'fruits', width = 0.9, color = ["#c9d9d3", "#718dbf", "#e84d60"], source = data)
vbar = p.vbar(x = 'fruits', width = 0.5, top = 'total', source = ColumnDataSource(df))
vbar.visible = False

radiogroup = RadioGroup(labels = ["StackedBar", "Bar"], active = 0,)
radiogroup.callback = CustomJS(args = dict(vbar_stack = vbar_stack, vbar = vbar), code = """
    for (i in vbar_stack)
        vbar_stack[i].visible = false;

    vbar.visible = false;

    if (cb_obj.active == 0)
        for (i in vbar_stack)
            vbar_stack[i].visible = true;
    else if (cb_obj.active == 1)
        vbar.visible = true; """)

layout = Row(p, radiogroup)
show(layout)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks tony..can i follow the same process to toggle  between  bar or stacked bar..actually i am new to bokeh..

Comment: Yes. you can. I changed the code to make it more explicit. One remark: please next time provide complete (but minimal) and runnable code including imports. Thanks

Comment: when i am tryingt to toggle between stacked bar or bar graph..stacked bar is plotting proper...but when i click on bar it's plot only last value of the..its breaking the loop

Comment: You can provide your code as a new answer here so I can have a look (or edit code in your original question if you can?)

Comment: Can you also put somewhere on the Internet your full CSV file and reference it in your question? Or you could paste a few lines from the CSV file in you question just to show the data structure.

Comment: added image of csv file

Comment: When I run your code everything works OK. If you are not using the latest Bokeh v1.1.0 then I suggest you update to the latest one.

Comment: What I just said is that I copied your new code from your modified question and It works. So I don't know how can I help you any further?

Comment: i your output also ..last value is plotting in bar graph that is salseforce..microsoft and SAS is not coming

Comment: Tank you so much Tony

Answer (score 1):

See below your code with some small corrections:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.core.properties import value
from bokeh.models.widgets import Paragraph, PreText, RadioButtonGroup
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.models.widgets import CheckboxGroup, RadioGroup
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, LabelSet, CustomJS, Row
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, save
from bokeh.transform import dodge
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis

colors = ["#c9d9d3", "#718dbf", "#e84d60"]

dataframe = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Experience.csv'))

source = ColumnDataSource(dataframe)
exp = dataframe['Experience']
ys = list(dataframe.keys())
ys.remove('Experience')
TOOLTIPS = [("Experience", "@Experience")]

p = figure(x_range = exp, y_range = (0, 100), plot_height = 350, tools = ['hover', 'save', 'reset', 'zoom_out', 'zoom_in', 'pan', 'box_zoom'], tooltips = TOOLTIPS)
stacked = p.vbar_stack(stackers = ys, x = 'Experience', color = colors, source = source, legend = [value(x) for x in ys], name = ys, width = 0.5,)

colorList = Viridis[len(ys)]
labels = []
bars = []
for y, offset, color in zip(ys, [-0.25, 0, 0.25], colors):
    bar = p.vbar(x = dodge('Experience', offset, range = p.x_range), top = y, width = 0.2, source = source, color = color)
    bar.visible = False
    bars.append(bar)

radiogroup = RadioGroup(labels = ["StackedBar", "Bar"], active = 0,)
radiogroup.callback = CustomJS(args = dict(stacked = stacked, bars = bars), code = """
    for (i in stacked)
        stacked[i].visible = false;

    for (i in bars)
        bars[i].visible = false;

    if (cb_obj.active == 0)
        for (i in stacked)
            stacked[i].visible = true;
    else if (cb_obj.active == 1)
        for (i in bars)
            bars[i].visible = true; """)

layout = Row(p, radiogroup)
show(layout)
```

[image]