# How to display plot in Bokeh Div?

Tags: bokeh

Here's my plot:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure

plot = figure()
plot.circle([1,2], [3,4])
```

Here's my div:

```
myDiv = Div(text="<b>I want my plot to go in here!</b>", style={'color': 'blue'})
```

I want to be able to run the following code to see my plot:

```
show(myDiv)
```

**How do I get a plot into my div?**

Comment: Could you explain why you want to do that?

Comment: I have 5 plots in total, however I am tasked with only showing one at a time depending on what the user chooses to view from a dropdown list. My colleague has created all 5 plots as 5 separate graphs (instead of the same plot with different lines). So my approach is to put all 5 different plots into 5 different divs, and only show the relevant div, hiding the others, depending on what the user selects. Obviously this is an unnecessarily complicated approach, but I dont see how else I can selectively display one of 5 plots in the same space on my dashboard.

Comment: Then if you can fit all your plots in one `figure` I would suggest using glyph visibility switching using `renderer.visible = false/true` like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56042740/how-to-change-chart-type-based-on-user-slection-radion-button-in-bokeh) or if you cannot fit them in one `figure` then you could use [tabs](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/1.0.4/docs/reference/models/widgets.panels.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I wrote in the comments I suggest using [Tabs](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/1.0.4/docs/reference/models/widgets.panels.html)
Another option is to build a Bokeh server app that will remove / add a plot dynamically in the layout.

Run the code below in Terminal (Bokeh v1.1.0) using `bokeh serve --show app.py`:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Column, Select
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, figure, Figure
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 2), columns = ['plot1', 'plot2'])
source = ColumnDataSource(df)

def callback(attr, old, new):
    if new == "plot1":
        layout.children.remove(p2)
        layout.children.append(p1)

    if new == "plot2":
        layout.children.remove(p1)
        layout.children.append(p2)

select = Select(value = "plot1", options = ["plot1", "plot2"])
select.on_change('value', callback)

layout = Column()
layout.children.append(select)

p1 = figure(title = 'plot1')
p1.line(source = source, x = 'index', y = 'plot1')
p2 = figure(title = 'plot2')
p2.line(source = source, x = 'index', y = 'plot2')

layout.children.append(p1)

curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve can be easily done with a CustomJS callback assigned to your input widget.

Instead of creating a div, create a layout object like a Column. Pass it, along with the 5 plots, to your callback as arguments (refer to CustomJS documentation).

Then, you can do this:

```
layout_model.child = your_chosen_plot
layout_model.change.emit()
```

This will only show the selected plot while hiding the others. You can also access the `visible` property of each label individually.